# UITableViewCell indentation funkiness

Tags: ios, uitableview, tttattributedlabel

No existing questions quite get at what is happening in my app.

Indentation levels in my UITableViewCell subclass are sporadically either at 1 or 0. The text in the cell will either indent or hug the left margin (seemingly at random) as cells are en- and de-queued. I set the level in `cellForRow:`, I set the level in my subclass's `configure:` method, I implement `indentationLevelForRow:`. None of these has a noticeable effect.

The one thing I can reproduce is that the indentation collapses (level <- 0) when I touch a cell. Another touch doesn't toggle it. I write 'touch' here because this happens even if `willSelect:` returns `nil`; Scrolling after these touches sporadically resets levels to 1.

The one thing that might be the problem is that the content view contains a single instance of a 3rd party UILabel subclass `TTTAttributedLabel`. I don't know much about this code, but there is method, `setText:afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:` which block completion/callback is implemented and could be affecting things. But that doesn't seem to be the case, because nilling the callback makes no noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up reimplementing the whole view in a Storyboard, and after quite a bit of trial and error with AutoLayout, managed to get the whole thing to work without any bugginess.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't say with certainty either way, but I would not assume that `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` applies to a custom subview, like `TTTAttributedLabel` in your case. That is to say, I would assume it only impacts the cell's standard subviews (`textLabel`, `imageView`, etc).

If you require custom indentation levels for custom subviews, I expect you'll need to implement that yourself. You can certainly continue to implement that delegate method to centralize the logic, but you'll likely need to use the result of that method when laying out your cell.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. It's not that I wanted a custom indentation as such, but that the left boundary between the TTTAttributedLabel and the contentView was changing when I didn't want it to.